# Bug in Tagged Questions filter / show in Unanswered Tag

Tags: bug, google-chrome, ios

iOS 13.2.3

Google Chrome browser app

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

The **Unanswered** Tag can't be selected.

If I select **Unanswered** that changes to **Votes**.

[Screen record](https://youtu.be/wHRzICrvoLk)